# Loop over month names in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm learning the 'for loop' command in R and I wanted to create a code that told you your zodiac sign.

```
m <- c("January", "February", "March", "April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
  

for(m in "January":"December") {
  
  if (m == "March"|"April" )
    next
}

print(paste("You are an Aries"))
```

When I run this I receive the errors 'Error in "January":"December" : NA/NaN argument' and '2: In "January":"December" : NAs introduced by coercion'. How do I remove those?

Comment: This is not valid R code: `"January":"December"`. What are you attempting? To iterate across all items of vector/llist, simply loop on object: `for(item in m)  ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I was just trying to say m for January - December. I'm still new at R.

Answer (score 2):

Any of these three snippets will print the names of each month except for March and April. `month.name` is a vector that is built into R containing the names of the months.

```
for(m in month.name) {
  if (m %in% c("March", "April")) next
  print(m)
}

for(m in setdiff(month.name, c("March", "April"))) print(m)

print(setdiff(month.name, c("March", "April")))
```

Comment: How would I print only April and march?

Comment: `print("March"); print("April")` or `print(c("March", "April"))` or use `cat` (see `?cat`).

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in vector with month names: [`month.name`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Constants.html).

To make a [`for`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html) loop just type:

```
for(i in month.name) {...}
```

To check whether the month is March or April, use [`%in%`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html), e.g.:

```
if (i %in% c("March", "April") {...}
```

So your code could be:

```r
for(i in month.name) {
  if (i %in% c("March", "April")) {
    print(paste(i, "- you are an Aries."))
  } else {
    print(paste(i, "- you are not in Aries."))
  }
}
#> [1] "January - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "February - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "March - you are an Aries."
#> [1] "April - you are an Aries."
#> [1] "May - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "June - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "July - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "August - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "September - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "October - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "November - you are not in Aries."
#> [1] "December - you are not in Aries."
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still new at R so it's a learning process.